# How to use an index on a list of values?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have a query with a join on mytable unique indexed on (col1,col2)

```
explain
...
join mytable on col1=1 and col2=2
```

shows the correct use of the index with `type: eq_ref`

But when using a list the index is not used anymore

```
join mytable on col1=1 and col2 in (2,3,4)
```

`Extra: Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1);`

This gives the same result:

```
join mytable on (col1,col2) in ((1,2),(1,3),(1,4))
```

Is there a way to use an index when providing a list of values?

Comment: It may depend on the version, but certainly in my (rather old) version of sql, this is the case. So, the solution is to write it as a series of parenthesised ORs.

Answer (score 0):

- Normally one does not `JOIN x ON c = constant`.  The `ON` clause should specify how this table is related to the other table(s).  The `WHERE` clause should provide for filtering, such as `col1=1 and col2=2`.
- "Row constructors" have long existed, but only recently (5.7.3) are they the least bit optimized.  What version are you running?  Even with the latest version, I would expect `col1=1 and col2 in (2,3,4)` to be optimized at least as well as the row-constructor approach.
- `OR` often prevents any optimization.  And perhaps it is never faster than some alternative.
- We need to see the entire query, the `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there could be other issue lurking in the shadows.